# Preserve "unowned" URL in browser after redirect

Tags: domains, redirects

So, my university's communications department plans to provide a shared infrastructure for all departments to build websites on. However, my lab has an urgent need to publish a website now. I've built the page on my personal account at Bluehost and the communications department has given me their blessing to run with it until their infrastructure is ready.

They've even provided me with a redirect, unfortunately after the redirect the URL becomes that of my server.

Specifically:

`www.university.com/path` becomes `www.myserver.com/path`

I would like to show the content at `www.myserver.com/path` as if it were `www.university.com/path`.

The catch is, I don't personally control the `www.university.com domain` - I can only work with the redirect they've given me.

Is this possible?

I'd prefer to do this with .htaccess somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the supplied redirect and can't control anything else on the university's server then this is not possible. (They would need to setup mod_proxy or, as a "cheap" workaround a single page document with an IFRAME containing your site.)

If you do go ahead with this then when you eventually move the site to the university's server, setup a redirect from your server to the university.

Comment: Oooo that's still helpful. I might ask them to create me that iframe page since it's temporary anyway. Thanks very much! :-)